# Querying the AWS Pricing API via R

Tags: r, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to query the AWS pricing endpoint via R but I'm getting a 403 error.

I've looked around for generic examples of running AWS endpoints in R but really am not finding to much.  Any ideas?

```
library(aws.signature)
library(httr)

# validate arguments and setup request URL
current <- Sys.time()
d_timestamp <- format(current, "%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ", tz = "UTC")

hdrs <- list(`Content-Type` = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
             Host = "apigateway.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
             `x-amz-date` = d_timestamp)

params <- signature_v4_auth(
  datetime = d_timestamp,
  region = "us-east-1",
  service = "execute-api",
  verb = "GET",
  action = "iMetaAPI",
  query_args = list(),
  canonical_headers = hdrs,
  request_body = "json",
  key = "***********",
  secret = "***************",
  session_token = NULL,
  query = FALSE,
  algorithm = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256",
  verbose = TRUE)


a <- GET("https://api.pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
         query = params)
```

Comment: just to be sure, when you run it, do you have actual values for key and secret, and not just asterixes? A 403 error suggests to me that your credentials are no good.

Comment: @alex_danielssen - yes, I have the actual value for the key and secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the `paws` package to query the AWS Price List Service API. [Paws](https://paws-r.github.io/) provides access to the full suite of AWS services from within R similar to what boto3, the official AWS SDK for Python, offers to Python users.

In the example below I use a pricing client to fetch all locations where Amazon SageMaker is currently available. I use the `purrr` package to parse the responses.
I stored my AWS credentials (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY) in `.Renviron` which is the reason you don't see them in the code below.

```
library(paws)
library(purrr)

# Create pricing client
pricing_client <- pricing()

# Fetch metadata information of the SageMaker service
sm_metadata <- pricing_client$describe_services(
   ServiceCode = "AmazonSageMaker")

str(sm_metadata)
#> List of 3
#>  $ Services     :List of 1
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ ServiceCode   : chr "AmazonSageMaker"
#>   .. ..$ AttributeNames: chr [1:34] "productFamily" "automaticLabel" "volumeType" "memory" ...
#>  $ FormatVersion: chr "aws_v1"
#>  $ NextToken    : chr(0) 

# Store available SageMaker service attribute names in a vector
sm_attributes <- sm_metadata %>% 
  pluck("Services", 1,  "AttributeNames")

tail(sm_attributes)
#> [1] "groupDescription" "currentGeneration" "integratingService" "location" "processorArchitecture" "operation" 

# Fetch all locations where the SageMaker service is available
sm_locations <-  pricing_client$get_attribute_values("AmazonSageMaker", "location") %>% 
  .[["AttributeValues"]] %>% 
  map_chr(function(x) x[["Value"]])

sm_locations
#> [1] "AWS GovCloud (US-West)"    "Any"                       "Asia Pacific (Hong Kong)" 
#> [4] "Asia Pacific (Mumbai)"     "Asia Pacific (Seoul)"      "Asia Pacific (Singapore)" 
#> [7] "Asia Pacific (Sydney)"     "Asia Pacific (Tokyo)"      "Canada (Central)"         
#> [10] "EU (Frankfurt)"            "EU (Ireland)"              "EU (London)"              
#> [13] "EU (Paris)"                "EU (Stockholm)"            "Middle East (Bahrain)"    
#> [16] "South America (Sao Paulo)" "US East (N. Virginia)"     "US East (Ohio)"           
#> [19] "US West (N. California)"   "US West (Oregon)"
```